# Pandas dataframe rearrangement stack to two value columns (for factorplots)

Tags: python, pandas, stack, cumsum

I have been trying to rearrange my dataframe to use it as input for a factorplot. The raw data would look like this:

```
  A B C  D
1 0 1 2 "T"
2 1 2 3 "F"
3 2 1 0 "F"
4 1 0 2 "T"
...
```

My question is how can I rearrange it into this form:

```
  col val val2
1  A   0  "T"
1  B   1  "T"
1  C   2  "T"
2  A   1  "F"
...
```

I was trying:

```
df = DF.cumsum(axis=0).stack().reset_index(name="val")
```

However this produces only one value column not two.. thanks for your support

Comment: Do you want to perform `cumsum` on the values and then reshape it according to your desired `DF` or simply reshape the values without performing the `cumsum` operation because you've got answers for the latter case?

Answer (score 3):

I would use melt, and you can sort it how ever you like

```
pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['index','D'], value_vars=['A','B','C']).sort_values(by='index')
Out[40]: 
    index  D variable  value
0       1  T        A      0
4       1  T        B      1
8       1  T        C      2
1       2  F        A      1
5       2  F        B      2
9       2  F        C      3
2       3  F        A      2
6       3  F        B      1
10      3  F        C      0
3       4  T        A      1
7       4  T        B      0
11      4  T        C      2
```

then obviously you can name column as you like

```
df.set_index('index').rename(columns={'D': 'col', 'variable': 'val2', 'value': 'val'})
```

Comment: Order of magnitude better than my answer

Comment: @piRsquared appreciate that coming from you!

Answer (score 1):

consider your dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [0, 1, 2, 'T'],
        [1, 2, 3, 'F'],
        [2, 1, 3, 'F'],
        [1, 0, 2, 'T'],
    ], [1, 2, 3, 4], list('ABCD'))
```

[image]

***solution***

```
df.set_index('D', append=True) \
    .rename_axis(['col'], 1) \
    .rename_axis([None, 'val2']) \
    .stack().to_frame('val') \
    .reset_index(['col', 'val2']) \
    [['col', 'val', 'val2']]
```

[image]